# What exactly is the use of partial pressure of a component?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

Is partial pressure the actual pressure a component contributes in a mixture? What is the physical essence of partial pressure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The partial pressure is the pressure, produced by a certain constituent gas in mixture of gases, if it occupied the whole volume. This notion makes sense only for ideal non-interactings cases, for which *Dalton's law* is valid - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalton%27s_law. For those :
$$
p_{total} = \sum_i p_i
$$
In case of interactions, substances will affect each other, and the total pressure could be got only in a more complicated way.

Comment: Partial pressure is also used to establish the partial molar properties of the chemical components of an ideal gas mixture, including partial molar entropy and partial molar Gibbs free energy (aka, chemical potential).  In the later case, the fugacity of a chemical component in a gas mixture is equal to its partial pressure.